# How to use SynthLookAndFeel in a modular java application?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, java-module, synth

I'm trying to use the `SynthLookAndFeel` class but cannot make it work in my modular application.

I went back to basics with the official [Synth Application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/lookandfeel/index.html#SynthApplication) sample from the [Java Tutorial page on The Synth Look And Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html), and just added a `module-info.java` file with the following contents:

```
module SynthApplication {
    requires java.desktop;
}
```

It builds OK, but when run, the console shows a `NullPointerException` stack trace pointing to `java.desktop/sun.awt.SunToolkit.getImageFromHash(SunToolkit.java:653)`, and only a blank window is displayed.

The issue seems to lie in the resolution of the images (e.g. `images/button.png`) that are referenced in the `buttonSkin.xml` definition of the L&F: Image paths are converted to a pseudo-package name (`lookandfeel.images`) which is not exported to the `java.desktop` module.

I tried to add `exports lookandfeel;` to `module-info.java` => same error

I tried to add `exports lookandfeel.images;` to `module-info.java` => build error `Error:(4, 24) java: package is empty or does not exist: lookandfeel.images`

Is there a way to make the image resolution work or is SynthLookAndFeel purely incompatible with java modules ?

Thanks. Vicne.

Note: I'm using openJdk 14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after more code digging in the JDK, I discovered that it tested if the module was "open" (aka open to introspection). So I tried to declare the module as "open" as follows:

```
open module SynthApplication {
    requires java.desktop;
}
```

And woo-hoo it worked.

OK, learned something: `SynthLookAndFeel` must be part of an open module to work.

Hope it can help others.